# rails - "apache cannot run because another program is using its port"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

i downloaded and ran instant rails and i got that message

how do i fix this problem?

what is the other application that might be using this port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out which process is using a port on Windows run `netstat -ano` at the command line. It will print a list like the following:

```
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1784
TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2460
```

Look for a line with a local address using the port you are interested in (it looks like Instant Rails tries to start Apache on port 80) and then check the PID in Task Manager. In the above example, port 80 is being used by the process with process id 2460.

Comment: phil thanks so much for your help

on port 80 i am getting 5812
in task manager i was not able to find this

Comment: @every_answer You may need to tell Task Manager to show processes from all users. Also, by default it doesn't show the PID column, so you may need to add it with Select Columns from the View menu.

Comment: how do i show processes from all users? i believe there's only one user any way,  i do see the PIDs but 5812 its not there

Comment: @every_answer There should be a button or check box at the bottom of the Processes tab called 'Show processes from all users'. Even though there is only one user on the system, the process may be running as one of the built-in system or service accounts.